# Why do my MCU's capacitive voltage divider results change with different power supplies?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, pic, capacitance, microchip

I've started experimenting with the onboard capacitive voltage divider inside the PIC18F47Q43. I've had success getting it up and running and getting usable results. This is the block diagram of it:

[image]

However, I keep finding that the behaviour changes when I plug my board into a different power supply. Say I use the onboard power of the PicKit 4 programmer to program and set things up, then if I remove it, and plug it into a desktop power supply, I get different results. Sometimes they're higher, sometimes lower, sometimes they have a greater range.

I know capacitive touch is a sensitive beast, so I keep the capacitive touch node wiring all short and tidy. **I just don't understand how the power supply affects the ADC readings on my MCU**.

1. Would anyone know why this is happening?
2. Can you help me figure out how to get consistent readings across power supplies.

Comment: Maybe the Vdd is a reference voltage for the ADC.

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the power supply and capacitive touch portions of the schematic please?  A physical photo may also be helpful to ensure any answer considers all possible contributors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common reason for power supply interaction with touch systems is high-frequency noise from the switching power supply getting into the touch system.

Switching power supplies typically work at hundreds of kilohertz - a similar range that the touch sensing is sensitive to.

I used to work on phones with touch sensing and it was a significant problem.

Ensure that that the circuitry is grounded to AC supply ground if possible. If not then choose  different power supply.

Comment: Yep, definitely grounding it/increasing the cap of common ground that helped me out greatly, thanks! How did you deal with floating grounds on mobile phones?

Comment: @ezra_vdj - floating grounds reduce the capacitance change so requires more sensitivity, it can also cause cross interaction where touching one pixel causes signals on other pixels. The main way to avoid power supply noise is to use frequency agility on the stimulation frequency; We used spot frequencies in the range 100kHz to 400kHz with periodic sampling of the noise at each frequency to check which had least noise. An additional difficulty is that the power supplies often use PFM to achieve high efficiency at low powers so there is a moving target as the phone power changes.